# SharePoint Event Receiver to create Lotus Notes Reminder

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, lotus-notes

What I'm trying to do is set up a SharePoint event receiver so that when an item is added to a SharePoint calendar, a reminder is setup in Lotus Notes with the same title/date/time.

I was able to create a Windows Forms Application that creates the Lotus Notes reminder, but when I put that code into a SharePoint event receiver, it doesn't run. I even tried putting some other code in the receiver that I know works, but with the Notes code in there, nothing runs at all.

Is it just not possible to do this because the Lotus Notes code needs to be run on a machine with a Notes client on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using interop classes, you need to have a Notes installation on the machine, otherwise the DLLs that expose the Notes COM API aren't there for you to call.  And this could be problematic if your SharePoint server is 64 bit, because IBM does not support the COM API on Win64.  It can be made to mostly work, but it's not a good idea to go down that road.

There might be, however, other possible ways to do what you want.  Domino can be configured for access via HTTP and supports web services and more recent versions support REST APIs.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below, I have Lotus Notes on my machine (if that's what you mean), but there's no Lotus Notes client on the SharePoint server. I'll definitely look into the HTTP and web services you mentioned, but since no one in my office has any control over our Domino configuration, that could be a dead end.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of a "SharePoint Event Receiver".  Where does that code run?  On your computer?  Or on the Sharepoint server?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it runs on the SharePoint server.

Comment: In that case, yes, there would have to be a Notes install on the SharePoint server.  (That's what I meant by "on the machine".)  And if that's also not under your control and impossible to get approved, then you will have to find another way.

Comment: That answers my question then. Thanks, fellow New Englander.

Answer (score 0):

As the Out of the box Lotus Search connector requires to have lotus on the local computer, I suppose you are right. You should have lotus on the local box.

It's logic actually, as the Lotus code requires to have the lotus libraries available, unless there is some http API or similar.

Comment: I have Lotus Notes installed on my computer (the one I'm trying to have receive the reminder), but if it requires any configuration of the SharePoint server, that's probably out of the question.